# Determine IP address of CONNECTED interface (linux) in python

Tags: python, linux, networking, ip-address

On my linux machine, 1 of 3 network interfaces may be actually connected to the internet. I need to get the IP address of the currently connected interface, keeping in mind that my other 2 interfaces may be assigned IP addresses, just not be connected.

I can just ping a website through each of my interfaces to determine which one has connectivity, but I'd like to get this faster than waiting for a ping time out. And I'd like to not have to rely on an external website being up.

Update:

All my interfaces may have ip addresses and gateways. This is for an embedded device. So we allow the user to choose between say `eth0` and `eth1`. But if there's no connection on the interface that the user tells us to use, we fall back to say `eth2` which (in theory) will always work.

So what I need to do is first check if the user's selection is connected and if so return that IP. Otherwise I need to get the ip of `eth2`. I can get the IPs of the interfaces just fine, it's just determining which one is actually connected.

Comment: What classifies an interface as being "down"? Will it not have a gateway? Will it have a gateway, but the gateway will be unreachable?

Comment: You really can't determine routing just by looking at the IPs.  More than one interface may route to the internet (think wired and wireless, as one example).  NONE of them may (directly) route to the internet, but may have proxies in the path that handle certain traffic.

Comment: There is no such thing as a connection to the Internet unless you establish that connection with some server in the Internet using ICMP, TCP/IP, UDP etc. Unless you talk to some service and get a reply, you cannot say you are connected to the Internet otherwise.

Comment: I think you're using the wrong tool here -- if you've got three connections to the internet you would traditionally solve this problem by bonding the connections such that your fastest connection services requests firsts and as it runs out of bandwidth you spill-over into your other interfaces. If any interface dies, you automatically offload to the interfaces that remain. If you read up on the iptables/routing linux docs you'll find much more reliable solutions than trying to test every few minutes if you're still 'up'.

Comment: That's not quite what we're doing. Our eth2 is a ppp connection that should ONLY be used if the other 2 aren't up.

Comment: `you'll find much more reliable solutions than trying to test every few minutes if you're still 'up'` I'm not trying to test every few minutes. I just need to tell the user what their current IP is. And all the interfaces have IPs, but the user will want the one it's actually connecting on.

Answer (score 0):

If the default gateway for the system is reliable, then grab that from the output from `route -n` the line that contains `" UG "` (note the spaces) will also contain the IP of the gateway and interface name of the active interface.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is here : http://code.activestate.com/recipes/439093-get-names-of-all-up-network-interfaces-linux-only/

```
import fcntl
import array
import struct
import socket
import platform
"""
global constants.  If you don't like 'em here,
move 'em inside the function definition.
"""
SIOCGIFCONF = 0x8912
MAXBYTES = 8096

def localifs():
    """
    Used to get a list of the up interfaces and associated IP addresses
    on this machine (linux only).

    Returns:
    List of interface tuples.  Each tuple consists of
    (interface name, interface IP)
    """
    global SIOCGIFCONF
    global MAXBYTES

    arch = platform.architecture()[0]

    # I really don't know what to call these right now
    var1 = -1
    var2 = -1
    if arch == '32bit':
        var1 = 32
        var2 = 32
    elif arch == '64bit':
        var1 = 16
        var2 = 40
    else:
        raise OSError("Unknown architecture: %s" % arch)

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    names = array.array('B', '\0' * MAXBYTES)
    outbytes = struct.unpack('iL', fcntl.ioctl(
        sock.fileno(),
        SIOCGIFCONF,
        struct.pack('iL', MAXBYTES, names.buffer_info()[0])
        ))[0]

    namestr = names.tostring()
    return [(namestr[i:i+var1].split('\0', 1)[0], socket.inet_ntoa(namestr[i+20:i+24])) \
            for i in xrange(0, outbytes, var2)]


print localifs()
```

Comment: somebody down voted ... if they care to comment it be will helpful for me to understand my mistake !!!

Comment: The poster's question is more abstract, the code you've posted in particular is about interfaces that have 'link' where as the poster says that each of the interfaces might have link, but might not be able to reach the internet.